# WPF deployment strategy dilemma.clickonce(limited customization)+autoupdate vs installer(unlimited costomization) no autoupdate

Tags: wpf, installation, clickonce, auto-update

I've been facing a deployment problem.I've built a `WPF application` with `visual studio 2008` and created an `installer`(msi) which works fine.But then it's pain to add `automatic` update to it. i've seen [this article](http://windowsclient.net/articles/appupdater.aspx) at windowsclient.net but it seems to be pretty old but could have been the perfect thing for me.Then i looked at the .Net Application `updater block v2.0` which uses `enterprise library june 2005` and for some reason it's not installing on my machine.

I thought i will need to use a more recent Enterprise library so i `installed and compiled Enterprise 4.1(october 2008)` but nothing better happened.To i decided to give a try to `CLickonce` deployment.After struggling with it, it was almost perfect.I realized that when i was testing the updates provided by the clickonce on my machine which is XP i didn't notice the need of having `sqlite dll in the GAC`. surely it was already there.I noticed it when i moved to vista that there is a problem.After checking the net i know `it's impossible to add a dll to the Global Assembly Cache`.
Now i'm stuck, i think i've hit a wall.Can any one share some of his experience? I'm willing to try the updater block if i can get help.

Thanks for reading this!!

Answer (score 0):

First, you can't use that updater block. It was for .NET 1.1. It was marked obsolete when ClickOnce deployment was added in .NET 2.0.

You probably don't need to install that dll in the GAC. In many cases, you can just include it in the deployment, and it will find the local reference and use it. It just depends on the dll. So here's what I recommend you try:

Add the dll to your project. Set the 'build action' to 'none'. Set 'copy to local directory' as 'do not copy'.

Delete the reference in your project to that dll, and re-add it. But instead of picking it from the GAC, browse to the one you just added to your project and select it. On the reference properties, set 'copy local' to 'true'.

Now when you run it, it will access the local copy instead of looking for one in the GAC.

Like I said, this works great in some cases. It works for SQLCE and DirectX, but not for something like Infragistics. Some assemblies really do have to be installed in the GAC. The only way you will know is if you try it.

If you DO end up having to put it in the GAC, you can create an MSI to do that and deploy it as a prerequisite to the ClickOnce application. So you can still use ClickOnce for your main app.

Comment: i've found a way to solve this.I 've tried the ssce and set the database its "Build action" to content and it's copy to output Directory to copy always and everything works fine in the deployed pc.I Still want to use and updater.Can you point me to a direction? thanks for the reply though